# TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am getting problem with Jquery timepicker(); function
Here it is

```
<link href="js/jqueryTimepicker/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqueryTimepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqueryTimepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqueryTimepicker/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

This is **HTML markup**

```
<div id="tableTime">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Monday</td>
                <td>Tuesday</td>
                <td>Wednesday</td>
                <td>Thursday</td>
                <td>Friday</td>
                <td>Saturday</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtMonday" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtTuesday" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtWednesday" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtThursday" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtFriday" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtSaturday" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**Jquery**
All of the above jquery files are loading well enough but it throws one error TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function
Help!!! I am no where

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtMonday").timepicker();
            $("#txtTuesday").timepicker();
            $("#txtWednesday").timepicker();
            $("#txtThursday").timepicker();
            $("#txtFriday").timepicker();
            $("#txtSaturday").timepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: why are you including the script twice?

Comment: Also, which JQuery timepicker library? [This one](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker)?

Comment: You do not include both the minified version and the full version.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah yeah the one you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

One of your imports may not be working correctly since I got it working in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvhpjuap/). Try redownloading the CSS/JS files and make sure they are in the correct locations. If that still doesn't work, you can use the [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-timepicker) for referencing the CSS/JS files.

Put the following in your HTML code and it should be fixed

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.1/jquery.timepicker.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.1/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Also, in future, I might suggest using a CSS class instead of individual id's [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/xjwc45nv/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.txt').timepicker();
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with your entire HTML code so I can take a look? Something may be getting overloaded.

Comment: That link seems to show everything working as intended. What isn't working there?

Comment: If you can't provide the exact code where it isn't working, I can't help you. Just saying that it's not working but linking to code that is working doesn't help

Comment: your first code snippet has an error in it. the CSS file is in a scripts tag.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem importing the files.
Look: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nt9h47xk/1/)

Check the external resources that I used.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtMonday").timepicker();
        $("#txtTuesday").timepicker();
        $("#txtWednesday").timepicker();
        $("#txtThursday").timepicker();
        $("#txtFriday").timepicker();
        $("#txtSaturday").timepicker();
    });
```

Comment: yes i think this is the issue, but how can i survive from it

Comment: You have to import all JS/CSS files on your code:
<script src="http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>

In this link the provider uses his external resources: http://jsfiddle.net/jonthornton/28uvg/

Comment: Best thing that you can do, is put all those files to your localhost. Then you can just import them like this:
<script src="../assets/js/jquery-timepicker/1.8.1/jquery.timepicker.min.css"></script>
(example)

Answer (score 0):

**you need to use 'jQuery' instead of the '$'** symbol to handle the document as jquery variable so put your `.timepicker()` function inside this block of code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      // code goes here
    });
```

So your code should be like this:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#txtMonday").timepicker();
            $("#txtTuesday").timepicker();
            $("#txtWednesday").timepicker();
            $("#txtThursday").timepicker();
            $("#txtFriday").timepicker();
            $("#txtSaturday").timepicker();
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <!-- Updated stylesheet url -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css">

      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <!-- Updated JavaScript url -->
      <script src="//jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
      <script>

      $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });

    $(function() {
      $('#timepicker1').timepicker();
    });
    $(function() {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
    });

    $(function() {
    $('#timepicker2').timepicker();
    });
      </script>

    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#E8E9E9;">
      <form method="post" action="makecleaningappt">

        <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date">
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="timepicker1" name="time">

            <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="date">
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="timepicker2" name="time">
      </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```